# Why does it typically make more sense to use a project's non WETH ERC20 token over a WETH token as a utility?

Tags: erc-20

I do not have any further details for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Because customizing your erc20 token enables you to fine tune all properties it has. One could dictate how the tokens are created and/or burnt, for example. Or maybe implement a method with which someone's balance can be deducted by penalty or something. Using an already deployed token, however clean, does not give you these options.